# Error while trying to hide the cursor in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I tried to hide the cursor in Unity using C# script. However, it returned this error message:

```
CS0117: 'Cursor' does not contain a definition for 'visible'
```

Here is the full code for reference

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cursor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 worldPosition;
    public GameObject cursorobj;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane;
        worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
        cursorobj.transform.position = worldPosition;
    }
}
```

note: there was no error except for the line 12

I copied the exact code from the tutorial website, and also searched Google for similar situations.
I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Can you link to the example you were copying from the web site? Note that you've called your own class `Cursor`, which may not be what you actually want to do...

Comment: Sure, https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-lock-hide-the-cursor-in-unity/
I also took a look at other websites too

Comment: What's your unity version? and make sure you don't have any script named "cursor"

Comment: Rename your class and the .cs file accordingly. I assume it's conflicting with Unitys "Cursor" class. Or use explicit `UnityEngine.Cursor.visible = false;`

Comment: That page specifically talks about this sort of problem - look for "The “Cursor does not contain a definition for…” error is a surprisingly common issue that happens as a result of duplicating script names."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your class and the .cs file accordingly.
I assume it's conflicting with Unitys "Cursor" class.

As an alternative, you could use an explicit call:

```
UnityEngine.Cursor.visible = false;
```

The `Using UnityEngine;` doesn't solve your problem as long as your class is called `Cursor` but the explicit call can solve this ambiguity.

Comment: Changing the file's name helped. I should be more aware next time. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that you are defining a class with the name "Cursor" which is shadowing the Cursor on namespace UnityEngine

So your public class Cursor is missing a 'property' for the visibility, then the compiler cant find that and that is the reason of the error

```
public static bool visible;
```

but you mean for sure the Cursor on the UnityEngine namespace then you can specifically refer to it as

```
 UnityEngine.Cursor.visible = true;
```

in that case the compiler will not complain trying to tell you that your own "Cursor" has no static property for visibility

Comment: `Cursor.visible` is `public static bool visible;` in unity API. Check: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-visible.html

Comment: let me finish my answer people!!